# Staghorn Fern Non-Hanging Planter

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, planting

I’ve just been gifted a staghorn fern and it’s outgrowing its nursery pot already. I read that you’re supposed to hang staghorn ferns either by mounting them or in wire baskets. Unfortunately my apartment is rented and doesn’t have any good hanging spots inside or outside. I’m wondering if it’s ok for me to plant the horn in a wire basket, but leave it standing on the table instead. For example, could I line a wire storage basket like the one in the picture [image]in moss and just plant the fern inside?

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion that has worked very well for me over the last ten years is to mount the stag horn on top of a hat stand.

I carefully separated my plant into two pieces and bound the two pieces either side of the top of he hat stand using hessian strapping. I used sphagnum moss and shredded coconut infill.

This provides the plant with plenty of room to grow out, around and down.

Every year the plant grows new shields, then new leaves. Make sure you do the transplant before the new shields begin to form, or a few months after (to let the shields harden off). The shields are very sensitive when new and damage easily.

The stand I used was coated steel and had the added benefit of hangers (designed for hats) that can be used for smaller plants in wire baskets or hanging pots. I purchased the stand from IKEA for $29 Australian dollars, so it was a relatively cheap solution.

Comment: Wow I’ve never thought of using a hat stand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As it grows, it will need space to hang down below the level where it is planted.

You could buy something like a cat tree, and use it as a stand for some other plants as well as the fern.

Or if you want something a bit more "up market", get a Victorian plant stand (or a modern replica) which is basically a pillar with a top just big enough to hold one plant pot.

Comment: Thank you! Those are great ideas!!!